# HTML : Div on Image

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have following html. How can I get this so that `dragDiv` is shown on top of the image?

```
<div id="pnlContainer" class="container">
    <img id="cropbox" src='1.jpg' />
    <div class="dragDiv" id="dragDiv">
    </div>
</div>

.dragDiv {
    width:400px;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:2px solid #CCCCCC;
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you're actually moving the dragDiv down and away from the image.  If you just change your code to -20px and -20px on the .dragDiv css, it will be over the image.

Or, you could give the "pnlContainer" relative positioning, then absolutely position both the "dragDiv", and the "cropBox" - you shouldn't need z-index - just by positioning, the div will appear over the image in this case.

Either way is just fine.  Bottom line is - positioning them correctly in this case will get the div over the image.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #pnlContainer {
        position: relative;
        }

    #dragDiv {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width:400px;
        background-color: transparent;
        border:2px solid #CCCCCC;
        position:relative;
        left:20px;
        top:20px;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        height:50px;
        }
    #cropbox {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: Cool That works. How ever problem with the width and hight of parent div as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/N87CX/5/  "pnlContainer" border is not covering child div.

Comment: I didn't realize that was part of your question.  Can you just put a border on the image instead of the containing div?

Answer (score 1):

You could make sure one element appears above the other using the [Z-index CSS property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp):

Comment: z-index is unnecessary in this case - he just needs to position them correctly, and the dragDiv will show on top of the image.